# If my explanation for output is correct

Tags: java, output

Code:

```
class TestA {
    public void foo(String... strings ) {
        System.out.println("TestA::foo");
    }

    public void bar(String a){
        System.out.println("TestA::bar");
    }
}

class TestB extends TestA {
    public void foo(String strings ) {
        System.out.println("TestB::foo");
    }

    public void bar(String a){
        System.out.println("TestB::bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestA a = new TestB();
        a.foo("foo");
        a.bar("bar");
    }
}
```

Output is

```
TestA::foo
TestB::bar
```

So `B::bar` is overridden and `B::foo` is overloaded and when a function is overloaded, it is the data type of the reference that matters not the type of object it is pointing to. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a function is overloaded, it is the data type of the reference that matters not the type of object it is pointing to. Am I right?

Yes.

Overloading is compile time binding and only the type of reference is known at that time. While overriding is run time binding and based on type of object the calls are executed.

Comment: @TedHopp: I wrote: `Overriding is run time binding`.

Comment: Okay, I'm obviously too sleepy to keep all the overwhatever's straight. Comments deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your analysis is, but here's what I see:

- `TestA.bar(String)` is overridden by `TestB.bar(String)`
- `TestA.foo(String...)` is inherited by `TestB` and then overloaded in `TestB` with `TestB.foo(String)`

However, because the compiler doesn't know that `a.foo("foo")` is being called for a `TestB` object, it doesn't know about the overloading. Thus it compiles it into a call to a method with signature `foo(String...)`. If it knew that `a` was a `TestB`, it would bind to `foo(String)` since that's a closer match (not requiring a conversion to an array argument).

Comment: Actually output is different in the case you mentioned.

Comment: @IanMcGrath - Ack. I see a typo in my test program. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

TestB class inherits TestA and it has overridden bar method and overloaded foo method, at the time of compiling the TestA a has the reference of the TestB so the overloaded method does not  get executed but in the case of overridden bar method a call to overridden method is done at runtime. Because the overloaded method are loaded at compile time and overridden method at runtime.